# Relax ssh rate-limit rules for certain ip addresses

Tags: ssh, iptables, ubuntu-12.04, rate-limiting

We've written some tools to automate common development tasks. One tool, for example, ensures all our git repositories are up-to-date. For this to work, our tool needs to connect to our git server and fetch the latest for each repository. We have many git repositories so this tool ends up creating many connections in a short timespan - throwing iptable's rate limit rule and locking us out for a while (not sure how long).

How can I disable this rate-limit for certain IP addresses (like our office)?

Comment: Sure would be useful if you showed you rules.  Rate limiting can be implemented in a few different ways.  Your answer will depend on what exactly you rules are.

Comment: Truth. I'm unclear where my problem actually stemmed from so I'm not sure what kind of information to provide. I assumed it was a common Ubuntu feature and thought this might have been enough to get someone started. I think I resolved the issue though and I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

throttle your requests down is always a better idea than creating hard to maintain exceptions in your security schema.